# How can u torrent download same files in the exact same location without rechecking?

Tags: download, bittorrent, file-sharing, utorrent

I have been using utorrent for quite sometime now.Recently I noticed a problem.

> When I download a file **partly** and remove the torrent and then again re-add the torrent I find that the **file starts downloading from the first** .However if I pause it immediately and **force re-check** the file it skips what i have downloaded before and then downloads from there.

So I have 2 questions
Firstly

> Why doesn't utorrent check the files automatically before downloading?

Secondly

> How come utorrent download the same exact files at the same exact location without disturbing any part of the previously downloaded file?

i use windows 10 and utorrent 2.2.1

Comment: "Why doesn't utorrent check the files automatically before downloading?" - It's not programmed to do that.  "How come utorrent download the same exact files at the same exact location without disturbing any part of the previously downloaded file?" - It is programmed to do this.

Comment: it actually used to check automatically

Comment: @SwapnavaChaudhuri Because its downloading different small packages and add them together at the end. It checks them to make sure the packages are in the right order and not corrupt or scrambled.

Comment: but why is it not checking automatically?

Comment: @SwapnavaChaudhuri - Because it is not programmed to do that or you don't have that option enabled.